# 7z - Can I extract the contents of only one folder in an archive from the console?

Tags: command-line, powershell, 7-zip

I have an archive with a structure like this:

```
foobar.nupkg
    foo
        herp.dll
        derp.exe
    bar
        lerp.dll
        nerp.exe
```

Now, I've got a batch file that extracts the contents to another directory:

```
7z e "C:\Users\Me\foobar.nupkg" "C:\Users\Me\Myfolder"
```

The problem is that this command extracts all the files into Myfolder when I only want the contents of, say, foo. Is there a way to accomplish this from the console, perhaps using Powershell?

Comment: Try `7z e "C:\Users\Me\foobar.nupkg" -o"C:\Users\Me\Myfolder" foo\*.*`

Comment: @DavidPostill This is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I only want the contents of, say, `foo`

You need to use the [`-o` (set Output directory)](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/output_dir.htm) option and then use a wild specification for the files you want to extract.

Use the following command line (untested):

```
7z e "C:\Users\Me\foobar.nupkg" -o"C:\Users\Me\Myfolder" foo\*.*
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Command Line Version User's Guide](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/)
- [e (Extract) command](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/extract.htm)

Comment: Simply use `foo\*` if you want to extract files without extensions as well ([docs](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/extract.htm)).